# How do I delete files that my app owns from QML?

Tags: application-development, qml

My app imports files from ContentHub and saves them into `~/.local/share/applications/${myappid}/Pictures/`. I would like to be able to delete them when the user no longer wants them.

How do I delete files that my app owns from QML?

Comment: I think you should write the part to delete the file with qt.
By qfile.h or qdir.h then link it to QML and extend the rest of your application

Comment: If you want, I wrote a program and I can share it with you